# AngularJs PDFTron CoreControls is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-mvc, pdftron

I'm developing an angular_js / spring web-app. I'm using pdftron library to view a pdf files and store it into indexedDB to using offline mode.

I imported a pdftorn library in my project and CoreControls file is present.
This is my common.js:

```
'use strict';

requirejs.config({

    "baseUrl": CDN_CONTEXT_PATH,

    paths: {
        "jquery": 'jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min',
        "jquery-ui": 'jquery-ui/1.11.4',
        "jquery-layout": 'jquery-layout/1.4.3/jquery.layout_and_plugins.min',
        "jquery-fullscreen": 'jquery-fullscreen/1.1.5/jquery.fullscreen',
        "handlebars": 'handlebars/1.3.0/handlebars',
        "bootstrap": 'bootstrap/'+ CDN_BOOTSTRAP_VERSION +'/js/bootstrap',
        "text": 'requirejs-text/2.0.14/text',
        "angular": "angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min",
        "angular-route": "angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min",
        "angular-touch": "angularjs/1.5.5/angular-touch.min",
        "angular-animate": "angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min",
        "pdftron": 'pdftron/'+ CDN_PDFTRON_VERSION +'/lib/WebViewer.min',
        "core-controls": 'pdftron/'+ CDN_PDFTRON_VERSION +'/lib/html5/CoreControls.js'
    },

    shim: {
        "bootstrap": {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        "angular": {
            exports: 'angular',
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        "angular-route": {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        "angular-touch": {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        "angular-animate": {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        "handlebars": {
            exports: 'Handlebars'
        },
        'pdftron': {
            exports: 'PDFTron',
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery-layout': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'jquery-fullscreen': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    },
    config: {
        moment: {
            noGlobal: true
        }
    }
});
```

this is my define controller:

```
define(['angular', 'angular-touch', 'pdftron', 'core-controls'], function(angular, pdftron, core-controls) {
var appControllers = angular.module('mbControllers', ['ngTouch']);
```

and this is where i'm using it:

```
  function storeOffline(docInfo, onComplete) {
          console.log("storeOFFLINE");
          var cacheHinting = CoreControls.PartRetrievers.CacheHinting;
          var partRetriever = new CoreControls.PartRetrievers.StreamingPartRetriever(docInfo.location, cacheHinting.CACHE);
          var doc = new CoreControls.Document(docInfo.id);
          doc.loadAsync(partRetriever, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                  onComplete(err);
                  return;
              }
              doc.initOfflineDB(function() {
                  doc.storeOffline(function() {
                      onComplete();
                  });
              });
          });
      }
```

this is chrome output:

> angular.js:13550 ReferenceError: CoreControls is not defined

Some advice guys?

Thanks.

Comment: `core-controls` hyphens cannot be used in variable names.

Comment: Thanks man, some time the answer resides in the simplest things:). Have a good day.